# How to display images in a grid in python's tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to insert photos into a grid in python's tkinter, and then display those photos in rows and columns.(number of rows and columns are depending on what you input)

I tried using appending list to insert picture into list but i can only display one column of it.

```
from tkinter import *

w = Tk()

w.geometry('1000x800')

p = 'picture.png'

img = PhotoImage(file=p)

for i in range(0, 5):
    photo_list.append(Label(w, image=img))

for j in range(0, len(photo_list)):
    photo_list[j].pack()
```

I want to display those pictures in both rows and columns.
for example, if row=3, column=3, the output should be:

[picture][picture][picture]

[picture][picture][picture]

[picture][picture][picture]

Comment: What is [picture][picture][picture][picture][picture]???

Comment: Those are sample of picture display because i can't put images there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with:

```
nr = 5 #number of rows
nc = 2 #number of columns

photo_list = []

for i in range(nr*nc):
    photo_list.append(Label(w, image=img))
    photo_list[-1].grid(row=i//nc, column=i%nc)
```

Here I make use of the [grid geometry manager](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) which allows to do what you want more easily than the [pack geometry manager](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm). Images are placed row by row.
`grid` accepts two arguments called `row` and `column` which are the indexes (starting from 0) of the widget in a 2D grid ideally drawn on the container surface. `tkinter` can determine automatically the dimensions of the grid and manage sizes.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That's what i'm looking for.

Comment: @SreyornLen if the answer was helpful, please consider to upvote / accept it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers